# AttributeError : module 'torchvision.datasets' has no attribute 'Kinetics400'

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, python-import, importerror, pysyft

I am importing the following modules :

```
from torchvision import datasets, transforms  
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset     
import syft as sy
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 7
      5 from torchvision import datasets, transforms
      6 from torch.utils.data import DataLoader, Dataset
----> 7 import syft as sy
      8 import copy
      9 import numpy as np

File c:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\syft\__init__.py:48
     46 from syft.core.common.serde.serialize import _serialize as serialize  # noqa: F401
     47 from syft.core.node.common.service.repr_service import ReprMessage  # noqa: F401
---> 48 from syft.core.node.device.device import Device  # noqa: F401
     49 from syft.core.node.device.device import DeviceClient  # noqa: F401
     50 from syft.core.node.domain.domain import Domain  # noqa: F401

File c:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\syft\core\node\device\__init__.py:2
      1 # syft relative
----> 2 from .client import DeviceClient
      3 from .device import Device
      5 __all__ = ["DeviceClient", "Device"]

File c:\Users\himan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site- 
packages\syft\core\node\device\client.py:16
      14 from ...io.location import SpecificLocation
      15 from ...io.route import Route
...
  (...)
   190             ),
   191         )

AttributeError: module 'torchvision.datasets' has no attribute 'Kinetics400
```

Can anybody please help how to resolve this error? I am not able to import the package.